# Calculate value of double summation of function over the pairs of vertices of a graph

Tags: python, numpy, graph

Given a directed graph G with node pair (p,q) we have

[image]

I want to calculate the value of this recursive function where L(p) denotes the set of undirected link neighbors of node p. This function is for the (k+1)th value.

I know how to calculate L(p) and L(q).

Here is my attempt-

```
from __future__ import division
import copy

import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.sparse as sp
import time
import warnings




class Algo():
    def __init__(self, c=0.8, max_iter=5, is_verbose=False, eps=1e-3):
        self.c = c
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.is_verbose = is_verbose
        self.eps = eps

    def compute_similarity(self, a):
        '''

        Note: The adjacency matrix is a (0,1)-matrix with zeros on its 
        diagonal.
        '''                                 
        a_transpose=np.transpose(a)
        a_undirected=np.add(a,a_transpose)

        self.num_nodes = np.shape(a)[0]
        current_sim = np.eye(self.num_nodes)
        prev_sim = np.zeros(shape=(self.num_nodes, self.num_nodes))

        #Determine the set of Neighbors for each node
        nbs = []

        for i in range(self.num_nodes):

            nbs.append(np.nonzero(a_undirected[:, i])[0])


        for itr in range(self.max_iter):

            if scipy.allclose(current_sim, prev_sim, atol=self.eps):
                break

            prev_sim = copy.deepcopy(current_sim)

            for i in range(self.num_nodes):
                for j in range(self.num_nodes):
                    if i == j:
                        continue

                    if len(nbs[i]) == 0 or len(nbs[j]) == 0:
                        current_sim[i][j] = 0
                    else:
                        #commonSet=0.0
                        differenceSetofp_ij=0.0
                        differenceSetofq_ij=0.0
                        commonSet=len(np.intersect1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]))/len(np.union1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]))


                        for x in np.setdiff1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]):
                            for y in nbs[j]:

                                differenceSetofp_ij+=prev_sim[x][y]
                                differenceSetofp_ij*=1/(len(np.union1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]))*len(nbs[j]))
                                #print differenceSetofp



                        for x in np.setdiff1d(nbs[j],nbs[i]):
                            for y in nbs[i]:

                                differenceSetofq_ij+=prev_sim[x][y]
                                differenceSetofq_ij*=1/(len(np.union1d(nbs[j],nbs[i]))*len(nbs[i])) 

                        current_sim[i][j] = self.c*(commonSet+differenceSetofp_ij+differenceSetofq_ij)


        if self.is_verbose:

            print('SimRank: converged after {0} iterations'.format(itr))
        return current_sim                  



if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = np.array([ [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])                    



    obj = Algo(is_verbose=True, eps=1e-2)
    start_time = time.time()
    S = obj.compute_similarity(a)
    print(S)
    print('Runtime: ', time.time() - start_time, '\n')
```

The output I am getting is not correct.

Comment: I've updated my answer and posted your code with corrections. It now returns `0.8` for `(b, c)` and for `(g, i)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expected answer `R_inf[1,2] = 0.8` and `R_inf[6,8] = 0.8` of OP's example `a` is the result of the algorithm applied to the directed graph `a.T`, *not* the undirected.

Here is `R_2` computed with OP's code (with some minor fixes) and with my code. And R_inf also computed with my code:

```
after 2 iterations with pp_loop:
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0      0      0.8000 0.4800 0      0      0      0     
0      0      0      0.4800 0.8000 0      0      0      0     
0      0.4000 0.4000 0      0      0.8000 0.1600 0      0.1600
0      0.3200 0.3200 0      0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.3200 0.3200 0      0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
after 2 iterations with OP:
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0      0      0.8000 0.4800 0      0      0      0     
0      0      0      0.4800 0.8000 0      0      0      0     
0      0.4000 0.4000 0      0      0.8000 0.1600 0      0.1600
0      0.3200 0.3200 0      0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.3200 0.3200 0      0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
in fixed point:
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0.8000 0.8000 0      0      0.4000 0.3200 0      0.3200
0      0      0      0.8000 0.4800 0.0960 0.0256 0      0.0256
0      0      0      0.4800 0.8000 0.1280 0      0      0     
0      0.4000 0.4000 0.0960 0.1280 0.8000 0.1600 0      0.1600
0      0.3200 0.3200 0.0256 0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
0.8000 0      0      0      0      0      0      0.8000 0     
0      0.3200 0.3200 0.0256 0      0.1600 0.8000 0      0.8000
```

My solution is faster and can compute the fixed point for networks up to `~1000` nodes.

A bit of explanation: The strategy is to express the recurrence relation by matrix algebra, because then we can leverage the highly optimized `blas` powered linear algebra that comes with numpy/scipy. For example, the inner sums - all of them in one go - can be done by multiplying the matrix R_k of current values with the transposed adjacency matrix. This may seem wasteful considering all the zeros in the adjacency matrix but `blas` is just very, very fast. Similarly, we can compute the sizes of the intersections by multiplying the adjacency matrix with its transpose, etc.

Assuming that the ultimate goal is not so much the sequence of R's but the fixed point we can save some more time by using a proper linear solver, because the recurrence is linear (+ offset). As writing the `n^2xn^2` matrix of this operation is not efficient we use an iterative solver that can use a `LinearOperator` in place of a matrix.

If tolerances are set tight enough both approaches yield the same fixed point.

Code including OP's with fixes:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import linalg

def mock_data(n, p):
    data = (np.random.random((n, n)) < p).astype(int)
    np.einsum('ii->i', data)[:] = 0
    return data

import copy

import scipy
import scipy.sparse as sp
import time
import warnings

class Algo():
    def __init__(self, c=0.8, max_iter=5, is_verbose=False, eps=1e-3):
        self.c = c
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.is_verbose = is_verbose
        self.eps = eps

    def compute_similarity(self, a, R0=None, use_undirected=False,
                           no_neighbor_policy='10'):
        '''

        Note: The adjacency matrix is a (0,1)-matrix with zeros on its 
        diagonal.
        '''                                 
        a_transpose=np.transpose(a)
        a_undirected=np.add(a,a_transpose)
        a_use = a_undirected if use_undirected else a

        self.num_nodes = np.shape(a)[0]
        current_sim = np.eye(self.num_nodes) if R0 is None else R0
        prev_sim = np.zeros(shape=(self.num_nodes, self.num_nodes))

        #Determine the set of Neighbors for each node
        nbs = []

        for i in range(self.num_nodes):

            nbs.append(np.nonzero(a_use[i])[0])
        R = []

        for itr in range(self.max_iter):

            if scipy.allclose(current_sim, prev_sim, atol=self.eps):
                break

            prev_sim = copy.deepcopy(current_sim)
            R.append(prev_sim)
            for i in range(self.num_nodes):
                for j in range(self.num_nodes):
                    if len(nbs[i]) == 0 and len(nbs[j]) == 0:
                        current_sim[i][j] = (
                            0 if (no_neighbor_policy=='00' or
                                  (no_neighbor_policy=='10' and i!=j))
                            else self.c)
                    elif i == j:
                        current_sim[i][j] = self.c
                    elif len(nbs[i]) == 0 or len(nbs[j]) == 0:
                        current_sim[i][j] = 0
                    else:
                        #commonSet=0.0
                        differenceSetofp_ij=0.0
                        differenceSetofq_ij=0.0
                        commonSet=len(np.intersect1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]))/np.maximum(len(np.union1d(nbs[i],nbs[j])), 1)


                        for x in np.setdiff1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]):
                            for y in nbs[j]:

                                differenceSetofp_ij+=prev_sim[x][y]
                        differenceSetofp_ij*=1/np.maximum(len(np.union1d(nbs[i],nbs[j]))*len(nbs[j]), 1)
                                #print differenceSetofp



                        for x in np.setdiff1d(nbs[j],nbs[i]):
                            for y in nbs[i]:

                                differenceSetofq_ij+=prev_sim[x][y]
                        differenceSetofq_ij*=1/np.maximum(len(np.union1d(nbs[j],nbs[i]))*len(nbs[i]), 1) 

                        current_sim[i][j] = self.c*(commonSet+differenceSetofp_ij+differenceSetofq_ij)


        if self.is_verbose:

            print('SimRank: converged after {0} iterations'.format(itr))
        R.append(current_sim)
        return np.array(R)

def f_OP(adj, c, max_n, R0=None, use_undirected=False, no_neighbor_policy='10'):
    return Algo(c, max_n).compute_similarity(adj, R0, use_undirected,
                                             no_neighbor_policy)

def f_pp(adj, c, max_n, R0=None, use_undirected=False,
         no_neighbor_policy='10', solver=linalg.gcrotmk):
    n, n = adj.shape
    if use_undirected:
         adj = adj | adj.T
    aind = np.where(adj.T)
    n_neigh = adj.sum(axis=1)
    n_inter = adj @ adj.T
    n_union = np.add.outer(n_neigh, n_neigh) - n_inter
    r_union = c / np.maximum(n_union, 1)
    if no_neighbor_policy == '11':
        n_inter[n_union==0] = 1
        r_union[n_union==0] = c
    elif no_neighbor_policy == '10':
        np.einsum('ii->i', n_inter)[np.einsum('ii->i', n_union)==0] = 1
        np.einsum('ii->i', r_union)[np.einsum('ii->i', n_union)==0] = c
    elif no_neighbor_policy != '00':
        raise ValueError
    avg_ngh = adj.T / np.maximum(n_neigh, 1)
    if solver is None:
        R = np.empty((max_n+1, n, n))
        R[0] = 0 if R0 is None else R0
        if R0 is None:
            np.einsum('ii->i', R[0])[:] = 1       
        for i in range(max_n):
            rowsums = R[i] @ avg_ngh
            rowsums[aind] = 0
            rec_sum = adj @ rowsums
            R[i+1] = r_union * (n_inter + rec_sum + rec_sum.T)
            if np.allclose(R[i+1], R[i], rtol=1e-7, atol=1e-10):
                return R[:i+2]
        return R
    else:
        def LO(x):
            R = x.reshape(n, n)
            rowsums = R @ avg_ngh
            rowsums[aind] = 0
            rec_sum = adj @ rowsums
            return (r_union * (rec_sum + rec_sum.T) - R).ravel()
        R0 = np.identity(n) if R0 == None else R0
        LO = linalg.LinearOperator((n*n, n*n), matvec=LO)#, rmatvec=LO)
        res = solver(LO, (-r_union * n_inter).ravel(), R0.ravel(), tol=1e-9)
        assert res[1]==0
        return res[0].reshape(n, n)

def f_pp_loop(adj, c, max_n, R0=None, use_undirected=False,
              no_neighbor_policy='10'):
    return f_pp(adj, c, max_n, R0, use_undirected, no_neighbor_policy, None)


# test on OP's example:
a = np.array([ [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

a = a.T
m, c, nnp = 2, 0.8, '11'

sol = {}
for f in f_pp_loop, f_OP:
    name = f.__name__[2:]
    sol[name] = f(a, c, m, None, False, nnp)
    print(f"after {len(sol[name])-1} iterations with {name}:")
    print("\n".join(" ".join("0     " if i == 0 else f"{i:6.4f}" for i in row) for row in sol[name][-1]))
print("in fixed point:")
print("\n".join(" ".join("0     " if i == 0 else f"{i:6.4f}" for i in row) for row in f_pp(a, c, 64, None, False, nnp)))

print()

# demo large network
n, m, p, c, nnp = 1000, 256, 0.02, 0.9, '11'
adj = mock_data(n, p)
print(f'size {n}, maxiter {m}, connection prob {p}, c {c}')
from time import time
t = time()
spp_loop = f_pp_loop(adj, c, m, None, False, nnp)
print('pp_loop: {:8.5f} sec'.format(time()-t))
print('squared rel err after {} iterations: {}'.format(len(spp_loop)-1, np.nanmax(((spp_loop[-1]-spp_loop[-2])/(spp_loop[-1]+spp_loop[-2]))**2)))
t = time()
spp = f_pp(adj, c, m, None, False, nnp)
print('pp: {:8.5f} sec'.format(time()-t))
def comp(a, b):
    print(np.allclose(a, b))
    print('abserr', np.nanmax(np.abs(a-b)), 'relerr', np.nanmax(2 * np.abs(a-b)/(a+b)))
print('fixed points equal:', end=' ')
comp(spp_loop[-1], spp)
```

Comment: What is the output coming for the dataset i have provided?

Comment: yeah they are mostly same as the output I am getting(since the scores keep on improving with every iterations)

Comment: but your scores for when i==j are 0.8 they should be 1

Comment: but I understand what you did with the matrix algebra they speed up the recursive definition and the scores are a good approximation of the scores from the recursive def

Comment: I also think that the implementation is correct..yours and mine but the expected output and the output me and you are getting are coming different..any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Only for `k=0`. If you look at recurrence step, there is a factor `c` in front of the entire thing. In case `p=q` the sums are `0` because the relative complement `L(p)\L(q)` is then empty, so that leaves ` c x 1` which is `0.8`.

Comment: Well if the expected result has definitely ones on the diag then there is something wrong with the formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161451/discussion-between-dev-123-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 4):

I'll use a NumPy array to hold the output (for ease of creation and indexing) and networkx for generating an example of a graph and providing sets of neighbors. Neither module is essential, as I'm not using any advanced features of them. Here is the setup:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.petersen_graph()    # example graph
vlist = list(G.nodes)      # list of vertices
V = len(vlist)             # number of vertices
kmax = 4                   # maximal k
C = 2                      # mysterious constant C
R = np.zeros((kmax, V, V)) # array of results, R[k, i, j]
np.fill_diagonal(R[0], 1)  # initialize R[0] by putting 1 on its diagonal
```

And here is the loop calculating R[k+1, i, j]. The main characters are Lp and Lq, the sets of neighbors of p and q. Python sets are intersected with `Lp & Lq`, joined with `Lp | Lq`, and subtracted with `Lp - Lq`. The lines with Rij assignments are pretty much verbatim copies of the given formulas.

```
for k in range(kmax-1):
  for i in range(V):
    for j in range(V):
      Lp, Lq = set(G[vlist[i]]), set(G[vlist[j]])
      Rij = len(Lp & Lq) / len(Lp | Lq)
      Rij += sum([R[k, p1, q1] for q1 in Lq for p1 in Lp - Lq]) / (len(Lp | Lq) * len(Lq))
      Rij += sum([R[k, p1, q1] for p1 in Lp for q1 in Lq - Lp]) / (len(Lp | Lq) * len(Lp))
      R[k+1, i, j] = C*Rij
```

Comment: I have calculated L(p) as a numpy array.I have edited the question to include it.

Comment: That's fine; feel free to adapt my solution for your specific data types. `set(array)` works just as well as `set(list)`.

Comment: ZeroDivisionError: division by zero occurs when implementing this code..any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: debug your code. It works on my machine.